# Scapy - send packets from pcap file with changed ip addresses

Tags: networking, network-programming, scapy

i have collected packets from networks and i saved it to file *.pcap
I want to change src and dst ip address and send it to network.
I wrote a simple script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
from scapy import *
from scapy.utils import rdpcap
from scapy.utils import wrpcap

packets = rdpcap("/root/Desktop/500000pkt.pcap", 1000)

for pkt in packets:
    if pkt.haslayer(IP) == 1:
        pkt[IP].src = "10.0.1.2"
        pkt[IP].dst = "10.0.1.1"

#for pkt in packets:
#   pkt.display()

wrpcap("/root/Desktop/500000pkt_changed.pcap", packets)
sendpfast(packets)
```

I am using eth1 interface.
After execute this script i see it:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
sending out eth1 
processing file: /tmp/scapylUGae4
Actual: 1000 packets (627010 bytes) sent in 0.09 seconds.       Rated: 6966778.0 bps, 53.15 Mbps, 11111.11 pps
Statistics for network device: eth1
    Attempted packets:         1000
    Successful packets:        1000
    Failed packets:            0
    Retried packets (ENOBUFS): 0
    Retried packets (EAGAIN):  0
```

In wireshark i observe network flow but nothing happens. Its silence.
Ping from computer to router is successfull.

What i doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know myself, but I presume that `scapy` doesn't re-write checksums when information is changed. That is probably what is causing your issues here.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `chksum` field to force scapy to re-calculate it.

```
del pkt[IP].chksum
```